# Properties of eigenvalues from differential equation

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

I have the matrix equation 
$$ M'(t) = A(t) M(t)$$
with the initial condition $M(0) = I$, with $I$ the identity matrix, and where both $M$ and $A$ are $3\times 3$ matrices, $A(t)$ is real and can be partitioned as $A(t)=B(t)+D(t)$ where B(t) is a skew-symmetric matrix and $D(t)$ is a diagonal matrix.

It seems that $M(t=T)$ has eigenvalues all with modulus less than one. How can I prove this?

Comment: Since the equation is linear, you can always rescale any soluution by a constant factor, $M\to \lambda M$. Hence the eigenvalues will be rescaled as well. You need an initial condition on $M$ to fix a unique solution (assuming $A(t)$ is reasonably well-behaved).

Comment: sorry I actually have a set initial condition. I rephrased the question to make it more clear.

Comment: What is $T$? You have not defined it anywhere.

Comment: $T$ is just any value of time not equal to zero. Obviously at time $t=0$ the eigenvalues are all equal to one

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that $M$ has all eigenvalues smaller than one. Take, for example, $D=0$ and $A = B$ a constant anti-symmetric matrix. Then 
$$
M(t)=e^{tA}.
$$
If all eigenvalues have modulus smaller than one, the determinant must have modulus smaller than one as well, but 
$$
\det{M}=\det{e^{tA}}=e^{t\textbf{trace}(A)}=e^0=1.
$$
If $D$ is a multiple of the identity matrix, the determinant can be made even larger than one.